# Completion handler in authentication service error

Tags: ios, swift, closures, completionhandler

Im performing a login operation and Im calling a custom Authentication service which has a method , which takes in a dictionary of username and password and does the API call. The function in the Auth service is as shown below.

```
    func loginWithUserData(userData: Dictionary<String, Any> ,completion: @escaping (_ success:DataResponse<Any>)->Void) 
    {
       NetworkManager.sharedNetworkManager.performNetworkOperation(url: myEndpoint().userSession(), httpmethod: .post, parameters: userData) { response in
        completion(response)
    }
}
```

My function which calls the Auth service is as follows:

```
    func performLoginAction(dictForLogin: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
       AuthenticationService().loginWithUserData(userData: dictForLogin as! Dictionary<String)
    }
```

Xcode complains that I have a missing argument for the parameter in my performLoginAction function. I dont know what to add in the completion: parameter. What is the format or what exactly should I return for the completion handler?

NOTE: I'm using Swift 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the completion handler

```
func performLoginAction(dictForLogin: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    AuthenticationService().loginWithUserData(userData: dictForLogin as! Dictionary<String, Any>, completion: { success in
       // do something with the `DataResponse<Any>` object
    })
}
```

or with trailing closure syntax:

```
func performLoginAction(dictForLogin: [AnyHashable: Any], ) {
    AuthenticationService().loginWithUserData(userData: dictForLogin as! Dictionary<String, Any>) { success in
       // do something with the `DataResponse<Any>` object
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this -

```
func performLoginAction(dictForLogin: [[String: Any]]) {
    AuthenticationService().loginWithUserData(userData: dictForLogin as! [[String: Any]]) { response in

    }
}
```